# While loop table with first row with fixed information

Tags: php, html, wordpress, while-loop, html-table

I got this while loop for creating a table with data:

```
<?php

$headers = $col = "";
while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
    $logo = get_field('logo');
    $name = get_field( "name" );
    $headers .= "<th> <img src=".esc_url($logo['url'])." alt=".esc_attr($logo['alt'])." /> </th>";
    $col .= "<td> $name </td>";

endwhile;
echo "<table><tr>$headers</tr><tr>$col</tr></table>";
?>
```

This is working great but I'm breaking my head over something I can't seem to figure out.

I need the first column to contain my own static data, not dynimic. Like in this image:
[image]

So the first column contains "Other spec 1", "Other spec 2" etc. etc.

Also this image contains a blue row to "break" the table and show some kind of new category.

Is it even possible to do this inside a while loop, if yes I could use some pointers to make this work.

Comment: The code you have shown would create a table with two rows only, one containing header cells, and one containing actual data cells. That doesn't match what your image shows at all.

Comment: What you want, is called a _control break_. Your data needs to be properly sorted by your control break criterion to begin with (that would presumably be your category here), and then inside your loop, you simply check if the value of that criterion for the current row, is the same as that from the previous one - if not, then it's time to output one of those blue rows first, before you output the actual data of the current record.

Comment: @CBroe, thank you for the response. I know I only got two rows now. I was allready struggling to get this part working and then I figured out that don't know how to get the first column filled with static content and also the control break. Neven done this before so that is why I asked for some help. Do you know if there is some kind of example I can take a look at? That will help me a lot:)

Comment: Your "static" content in the first column must be based on your categories here to begin with, I suppose (or where else are these names supposed to come from?), so in that case it would mean you increment a counter variable inside your loop, that you reset when the "break" occurs, and then just append that counter value to the category name when you output it in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming You want the output like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <th style="background:#00f"></th>
    <th><img width=100 height=100 src="https://source.unsplash.com/random"></th>
    <th><img width=100 height=100 src="https://source.unsplash.com/random"></th>
    <th><img width=100 height=100 src="https://source.unsplash.com/random"></th>
    <th><img width=100 height=100 src="https://source.unsplash.com/random"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:#00f;color: #fff"> NAme:  </td>
    <td> First  NAme </td>
    <td> First  NAme </td>
    <td> First  NAme </td>
    <td> First  NAme </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I think you can do like this:

```
$headers = '<th style="background:#00f"></th>';
$col = '<td style="background:#00f;color: #fff"> Name:  </td>';
while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
    $logo = get_field('logo');
    $name = get_field( "name" );
    $headers .= "<th> <img src=".esc_url($logo['url'])." alt=".esc_attr($logo['alt'])." /> </th>";
    $col .= "<td> $name </td>";
endwhile;
echo "<table><tr>$headers</tr><tr>$col</tr></table>";
```